# How do I use `our` variables in Perl

Tags: perl

I have following PL and PM files

Start.PL, ConfigReader.PM, BL.PM, Logger.PM

Code extract from ConfigReader.PM

```
Package ConfigReader
use Config::Simple;
use Logger;

our $configIni;
sub OpenConfigIni()
{   
    my ($cfg_ini_path)=@_;
    &Logger::LogMsg("**** OpenConfigIni starts ****","info");    
    &Logger::LogMsg($cfg_ini_path,"info");
    $configIni = new Config::Simple($cfg_ini_path);
    &Logger::LogMsg("**** OpenConfigIni ends ****","info");
}
```

Where Logger.PM is a custom module I have written using Log4Perl.

Code extract from BL.PM

```
Package BL
use strict;
use Logger;
use ConfigReader;

my %chash = %{$ConfigReader::configIni->param( -block => "UserDetails")};
```

Code extract from Start.PL

Start.PL is the entry point to my application which initiates Logger, ConfigReader

```
use strict;
use ConfigReader;
use Logger;
use BL;

&Logger::InitiateLogger();
&ConfigReader::OpenConfigIni("My_Config.ini");
my %qhash = %{$ConfigReader::configIni->param( -block => "ABC")};
```

Problem is

When i run Start.PL, the code fails with following error

```
Can't call method "param" on an undefined value at BL.pm line 9
Compilation failed in require at Start.pl line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Start.pl line 19.
```

(Ignore Line numbers)

It is pointing  to following in BL.pm

`my %chash = %{$ConfigReader::configIni->param( -block => "UserDetails")};`

If i comment `use Bl` in start.Pl, the script works fine that means

`my %qhash = %{$ConfigReader::configIni->param( -block => "ABC")};` works fine in Start.PL

what i am trying to achieve here is that

```
1. Use the ConfigReader.PM for handling the configuration related 
2. Make use of the our $configIni in all modules
3. Initialing the Logger and ConfigReader form start.pl whioch is the entry point here
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: OK works fine when i put the code `my %chash = %{$ConfigReader::configIni->param( -block => "UserDetails")};` inisde a method. Wonder why

Answer (score 2):

The initialization of `%chash` happens when BL.pm is loaded.  Which happens as part of the `use BL;` in Start.PL.  As you can see, execution of Start.PL at that point has not yet reached the call to `OpenConfigIni`, so the `$ConfigReader::configIni` variable has not yet been initialized.

The `%qhash` initialization in Start.pl happens after the config initialization call, so that works.

As you have discovered, initializing `%chash` from a function works.  Initializing your various modules explicitly through initialization functions is IMO better style than relying on load order to get the initializations right.  And mixing and matching doesn't work that well, as you've seen.